# How to pass a return value from a function in xTemplate?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Assuming we have the data below:

```
data: [{
    'D': 1
}];
```

Generally, we could access this data using the code below:

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for=".">',      
        '<p>{D}</p>',  //returns 1
    '</tpl>'
);
```

But, if I pass this to a `function`, it seems that it's just returning a string instead the value of '1'.

**Here is a sample code:**

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for=".">',
    '<p>{[this.getLetterD()]}</p>', //returns 'D'
    '</tpl>', {
        getLetterD: function () {
            ret = 'D'
            return ret;
        }
    }
);
```

I am trying to create a `function` that will get data from another `store`, store it to a `function` and render the value of the `function`. Please advise on how should this be passed in a `xTemplate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call like below:-

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for=".">',
    '<p>{[this.getLetterD(values)]}</p>', //returns 'D'
    '</tpl>', {
        getLetterD: function (vals) {
            var ret = vals.D;
            return ret;
        }
    }
);
```

**[Working Example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2i88)**

Hope this will help/guide you.

Comment: How would you do it for an array?

Comment: You can take an array and put `debugger` on `getLetterD` function to see how it works.

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2i92. Here is what I have done and it seems to be returning an `undefined` value

Comment: You are trying to add new property `ret` to `vals` object but it is `undefined`. You should call it like `var test = vals[name];`. See [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2i94)